# How to place text inside PrimeNG Doughnout

Tags: angular, primeng

[image]

```
this.data = { labels: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], datasets: [ { data: [], backgroundColor: [ 'green', '#51087E', '#ffd740', 'red', '#5500FF', ], }, ], };
      this.doughnutOptions = {
      responsive: true,
      plugins: {
        legend: {
          position: 'right',
        },
      },
    };

<p-chart type="doughnut" [data]="data" [options]="doughnutOptions" >
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a `label` property in your chart datasets:

```
datasets: [ { label: 'The Label', data: []....}]
// add this---^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Its not working